# Getting big Oh from summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, computational-complexity

> Merging two sorted arrays $A_1$ and $A_2$ with $n_1$ and $n_2$ elements, respectively, takes $O(n_1+n_2)$ time. This strategy begins by merging two arrays of size $n$ to create an array of size $2n$. It then merges that with an array of size $n$,and so on. Thus, the running time is
>
> $(n+n)+(2n+n)+(3n+n)+...+((k-1)n+n)) \tag{1}$
> $=2n+3n+4n+...+kn\tag{2}$
> $=O(k^2n)\tag{3}$

Why is the complexity of above $O(k^2n)$?

Can anyone explain mathematically how we can go from (1) to (3)?

Comment: From step 1 to 2, they computed what's inside the parenthesis e.g. $(2n+n)$ is rewritten as $3n$. From 2 to 3, we factor our $n$ and sum over $k$, which is $O(k^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes from (1) to (2),
then from (2) to (3).

If you want to bypass (2),
you can do this:

(1) is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} (jn+n)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} (j+1)n\\
&=n\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} (j+1)\\
&=n\sum_{j=2}^{k} j\\
&=n\left(\frac{k(k+1)}{2}-1 \right)\\
&<nk^2\\
&=O(nk^2)\\
\end{array}
$